# Django Display ImageField With Media Dir

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I am using Django 1.9.3. I am trying to display media files uploaded by say a user (e.g. imageFields).

HTML Page:

```
    {% for project in projects %}
        <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
```

Views.py:

```
def home(request):
    projects = AvailableProject.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')

    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', {'projects': projects})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] 
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('global', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'smilesite', 'project_static')),
    ('admins', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'admins', 'static')),
    ('accounts', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts', 'static')),
    ('mysite', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'static')),
    ('media', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')),
)
# print(STATICFILES_DIRS)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

# Define place to save media (e.g. pictures for all the projects)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class AvailableProject(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have literally went through every single stack over flow page on this and tried the following solutions, but still has not worked...:

```
<img src="{% static 'media/{{project.image.title}}.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

I don't know why the project.image.url is not showing the corresponding image correctly.

Comment: Do you have DEBUG = True in your settings.py? You need that to serve static/media with staticfiles_urlpatterns() and static(). Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve Oh, and looking again at your code, upload_to should be a relative path which will live inside settings.MEDIA_ROOT. You should not set it exactly MEDIA_ROOT. If you don't want any sub directories just use upload_to='/'

Comment: I set DEBUG=True yes.

What do you mean, so what should upload_to=?

Comment: A relative path which will live inside settings.MEDIA_ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was exactly what Joni Bekenstein said.

I changed this one line and everything worked:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Then {{ project.image.url }}, was the correct url.